# How does react.js know that data has changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using React.js I have written a simple app that gets json and uses some of that data returned to build html.

Although, when the JSON changes, the html does not. Am I missing something here?

**Here is my code -**

```
<script type="text/jsx">

var classNames = ({
    'auditNumber': "auditNumber",
    'audit-overview-box': "audit-overview-box"
});

var AuditOverviewBox = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="audit-overview-box">
                <h1 className={classNames.auditNumber}>{this.props.auditNo}</h1>

                <span>{this.props.creationDate}</span>

            </div>
        )
    }
});


var AuditBoxes = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            data: []
        }
    },

    componentWillMount: function () {
        this.dataSource();
    },

    componentWillReceiveProps: function (nextProps) {
        this.state.data(nextProps);
    },

    dataSource: function (props) {
        props = props || this.props;

        return $.ajax({
            url: '../json.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {

                this.setState({data: data});
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },


    render: function () {
        var data = this.state.data;
        console.log("data");


        var photos = data.map(function (audit) {
            return <AuditOverviewBox key={audit.auditNo.toString()} auditNo={audit.auditNo}
                                     creationDate={audit.creationDate}/>
        });

        return (
            <div className='myAudits'>
                {photos}
            </div>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<AuditBoxes />, document.getElementById('audits-div'));
</script>
```

**And the JSON -**

```
[{
    "auditNo": "a1201",
    "creationDate": "21/10/2016"
},
{
    "auditNo": "a1221",
    "creationDate": "21/10/2016"
},
{
    "auditNo": "a1211",
    "creationDate": "21/10/2016"
}]
```

Comment: can you edit the title ? it's misleading

Comment: as for your question, I think you're misunderstanding react, react will sync data between different components in the frontend automatically but it won't sync with the server automatically, though my answer needs someone with more expertise to verify

Comment: It's your responsibility to update the component's state if any data has changed. All that react does is rendering the data. You have to provide the (updated) data.

Comment: You're calling `setState`, which is what you're supposed to do. You'll need to do some debugging to see why that isn't happening.

Comment: note that your error uses this.props.url but the request uses a hard-coded value.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot push changes from the server to the browser (unless you use [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)). If you just need to update once in a while you should setup your code around the ajax request in such a way that it will perform a request every n seconds. The simplest solution would be using `setInterval()`

```
setInterval(
  function () {
    // your ajax code
  },
  5000
)
```

that way the request to the server will be done every 5 seconds. Please be aware that you can overload your server if you set the interval to short / have a lot of visitors.

Answer (score -1):

There are only two ways to change the data. You can use .setState method or directly set data to .state property and call .forceUpdate method of component, but this method is stritly unrecommended.
You can read more about it here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html